# using symfony authenticator with lexik jwt authentication

Tags: symfony, lexikjwtauthbundle, authenticator

I'm working on a symfony 4 project :
I created a documented API with API Platform, API expose data to be using from external and now,
I want to add a dashboard for administration.
The API routes are protected with jwt lexik bundle and i generated symfony authenticator.

My security.yaml file :

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\AppUser:
            algorithm: auto
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\AppUser
                property: email
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            json_login:
                check_path: /authentication_token
                username_path: email
                password_path: password
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
                    - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
                entry_point: lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout
                # where to redirect after logout
                # target: app_any_route
        refresh:
            pattern:  ^/token/refresh
            ...
    access_control:
        ....
        - { path: ^/administrator, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

I want to use the both : jwt token and symfony authenticator to be able to manage admin role and add an administration system to handle data for my project .
Now when i open the url :

```
http://my-project/administrator
```

I got this message :

```
{"code":401,"message":"JWT Token not found"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is kind old but just for the record I run into a similar need and solved it by using the isGranted Annotation as the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/security.html) suggests:

After creating the `roles` property as the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#roles) suggests for the `User` Entity you can validate if the user has access or not be declaring trought annotation on the method or the entire class:

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\IsGranted;

...

 /**
  * Require ROLE_ADMIN for *every* controller method in this class.
  *
  * @IsGranted("ROLE_ADMIN")
  */
```

There is no need to declare `access_control` section on the security.yaml.

Comment: i think is the best way to handle user access. thanks